# Find duplicates between some symbol

Tags: regex

Is it possible to detect that a string has 4 of the same letter separated by other characters such as the following: `abb*bbc` (`bb*bb`) or `a*aaa`? I try `(\S+\s*)\1` and it works fine for `abb*bbc` but it also finds `bb` and `abbcd` as well.

Comment: Does there have to be exactly one `*`, or can there be multiple (ex. `a*a*aa`)?

Comment: Does this *have* to be done with pure regex? If not, what programming language are you using?

Comment: I use Python, it's will be nice if we can find solution with regexp only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The (slightly ugly) regex-only solution would be:

```
([a-z])(?:\*\1\1|\1\*\1|\1\1\*)\1
```

That is:

```
([a-z])    any letter
(?:        one of the following:
  \*\1\1|   - a *, and then the letter twice
  \1\*\1|   - letter, *, letter
  \1\1\*    - letter, letter, *
)
\1         the fourth letter
```